# Nearest neighbor search in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nearest-neighbor, quadtree

I have implemented a 2-dimensional [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdtree) in Javascript ([check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/jacobmarble/Lechosa)), and I am using it for nearest-neighbor searches alongside [D3](http://d3js.org/).

I learned that there is [a quadtree implementation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-geom) in D3, but also discovered that the API documentation is sparse and Google searches are not fruitful. I would rather use a well-traveled library than my own reinvented wheel when possible.

**How do you perform a nearest neighbor search *using D3's quadtree***? By nearest neighbor, I mean:

- Populate the quadtree with 2-dimensional points
- Search for the quadtree-contained point closest to a new point that does not necessarily exist in the quadtree

Comment: Out of curiosity and nothing else, what are you using a JS K-D Tree for?

Comment: @Sajjan I have <circle>s in an <svg> and on mousemove the circle nearest the mouse position is highlighted. It is very smooth and scales well because nearest neighbor searches in a 2 dimensional K-D tree are O(log n).

Comment: Cool! Would it be possible to share your code (unless of course it is proprietary or private),I think I could learn a lot from it.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar added link to the content of my question, enjoy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brushing demo doesn't actually find the nearest neighbor, but rather finds quadtree points contained in a given rectangle.  (Try brushing an empty rectangle and it doesn't necessarily visit its nearest neighbors.)

I forked an example that efficiently finds the nearest neighbor in the quadtree to an arbitrary point - see http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6478178

Comment: Is nearest neighbour search is possible with latitude and longitude on leaflet.js maps?